# Which priority inversion avoidance protocol to use: priority inheritance and priority ceiling

Tags: rtos

I have knowledge of priority inversion and when it occurs. Priority inheritance and priority ceiling protocol capability of mutex are used to avoid priority inversion.

My query is which one of the above protocol to use for priority inversion avoidance or say when to use priority inheritance and when to use priority ceiling protocol?

We cannot use both protocol at same time to resolve priority inversion

Answer (score 1):

Priority Inheritance protocol avoids unbounded priority inversion but it cannot avoid deadlocks. On the other hand Priority Ceiling protocol can avoid deadlocks as well as it limits the priority inversion to only one level i.e. At a given time, a thread can block only one higher priority thread at max. 
So priority ceiling protcol is more sophisticated than priority inheritance protocol but it has more overhead. So in very safety critical systems priority ceiling must be used but otherwise priority inheritance may work as well if you want to keep the overhead small.